# Unable to load new url in WKWebView when opening app with a deep link

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview

I've been trying to implement a custom protocol deep link into my app, in such a way that when the app opens, it constructs the correct URL string, then uses the WKWebVeiw in the ViewController to display the page.

No matter what I do though, the URL either won't load, or it will throw an error saying that the WKWebView is nil.

Here is the code I am using:

In `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    var urlString:String = "https://example.com"

    print(url.scheme!)

    if url.host != "example.com" {
        print(url.host ?? "")
        urlString += url.host ?? ""
    }
    print(url.path)
    urlString += url.path
    print(url.query ?? "")
    urlString += url.query ?? ""

    print(urlString)
    if verifyUrl(urlString: urlString) {
        vC.url = URL(string: urlString)!
    }

    return true
}
```

In `ViewController.swift`:

```
var url: URL! = URL(string: "https://example.com")!

func loadPage() {
    let urlRequest:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```

I have tried:

- using a Property Observer on the URL variable (causes `Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`)
- calling `loadPage()` from `AppDelegate.swift` (same thing)
- calling `loadPage()` in `viewDidAppear()` (does nothing)

Nothing has worked so far. Any help you can give would be a massive help. Thanks in advance!